# Windows 10 / EDGE Browser can't print

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, printing, microsoft-edge

Has anyone had an issue where when you try and print from the EDGE browser it says it can't find the printer? It does not seem to see any of the printers as online.

Every other browser works fine.

My current fix was to switch everyone to FireFox but does anyone know why EDGE can't see any of the printers as online?

Comment: I'm experience this as well and can't find a fix. Printer works fine everywhere else, but anytime I try to print in Edge it says "We couldn't reach this printer". Is your printer connected via Wi-Fi (2.4 GHz band) by chance?

Comment: I had the same ridiculous issue, 2 computers with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue just now.

It seems that some Windows applications use Edge technology to access the printer settings:

- Edge itself
- Windows Photo Viewer

After some sort of windows update, whenever I opened a picture, it would say,

> we couldn't reach this printer. make sure the printer is on and you
>   are connected to the printer's network or try a different printer

after some research, someone has suggested to to change the driver in the printer properties advanced settings and it fixed it

these are all the steps I took:

1. search for the most up-to-date driver from the manufacturer site (I just googled my printer model and downloaded the driver from Samsung's site)
2. went into device manager (compmgmt.msc) and deleted the printer and checked the box to delete the driver as well
3. installed the new printer driver

**(problem persists)**

4. open Start > Devices and Printers
5. right-click the printer > printer properties
6. click change properties (to enable admin mode)
7. go into advanced > Driver > pick a different driver (for the same printer)

[image]

funny enough, after changing the driver once, any driver I picked worked and I didn't get the error again

[Source](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10579720/)

Answer (score 0):

Changing UAC settings to default fixed the issue for me.